# Identify the error in the proof and give a counter example to the conditional

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to (1) identify the error in this proof, and (2) give a counterexample to show that the conditional is false.

> **Proposition:**
> Let $u$, $m$, $n$ be three integers. If $u\mid mn$ and $\gcd(u,m) = 1$, then $m = \pm 1$.
>
> *Proof:*
> If $\gcd(u,m) = 1$, then $1 = us + mt$ for some integers $s$ and $t$. If $u\mid mn$, then $us = mn$ for some integer $s$. Hence, $1 = mn + mt = m(s + t)$, which implies that $m\mid 1$, and therefore $m = \pm 1$.

For the counterexample, I have:

Let $d = \gcd(u,m)$, then $a = dn$ and $b = dm$ for some integers $m$ and $n$. By Theorem 1.34 (from study guide), for positive integers $a$, $b$ there exists a unique positive integer $c$ such that $c = \gcd(a,b)$ and $c = ax + by$ for some integers $x$ and $y$. Let $c = 1$ and if $1 = ax + by$, then $1 = dnx + dmy = d(nx + my)$. Thus $d \mid 1$, and since $d$ is a positive integer, we conclude $d = 1$. So $d = ax + by$ for some integers $x$ and $y$. Thus $d = dnx + dmy$ and by the cancellation law, $1 = nx + my$, and $1 = \gcd(m,n)$.

Do I have the right idea with this or am I completely off track? If this is not correct for a counterexample any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

---

As for the error in the conditional, if $u\mid mn$ and $\gcd(u,m) = 1$, then $m = \pm 1$, I believe it is in "$m = \pm 1$". I believe that $m$ should be positive and be equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the counterexample, you want to use specific numbers. For example: $u=2, m=3, n=4$. If you check those, you'll see that they satisfy the premises, but not the conclusion. See if you can make more examples yourself, and then note what they have in common.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I keep forgetting that I can use numbers in counterexamples. That made it much easier. Also, if you don't mind, am I correct is saying that  s is being 'defined' in two different if-then statements. I also believe that s is being used incorrectly here, ' mn + mt = m(s + t)'. Should this read mn + mt = m(n + t) instead?

Comment: Something like that. It's like they tried to substitute $us$ for $mn$, but then it turned into $ms$ instead. You're right about that step being wrong, anyway.

Comment: It turned out that there was a typo on the exercise and us should have been mn.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: how is $s$ defined? Is it used consistently in the proof?

Comment: The s is being 'defined' in two different if-then statements. I also believe it is being used incorrectly here, ' mn + mt = m(s + t)'. Should this read  mn + mt = m(n + t) instead?

Comment: You're right that it's a typo in that final equality. But I was referring to the two different definitions. Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Sorry, I just can't see where the error is. Also, I'm not sure how to tell if the two definitions are interchangeable or not.

Comment: Try it for a moment with actual numbers. See G Tony Jacobs' answer for numbers to test. Now you have $us=mn$, which becomes $2s=3\times4$, which gives $s=6$. Now look at the other equation, $1=us+mt = 2s+3t$. If $s=6$, this becomes $1=12+3t$; you can't satisfy this with an integer $t$. Clearly, the values of $s$ are not the same, and one should instead use a different variable for one of the two equations - say, $uq=mn$, rather than $us=mn$. What impact does this have on the proof?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. I think I have everything that I need in order to complete the exercise. By using s in both equations this makes the proof false. Also, the t will not be an integer which it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error in that proof is the use of the variable $s$, since the existential instantiation states that

> If the existence of a certain kind of object is assumed or has been deduced then it can be given a name, as long as that name is not currently being used to denote something else

Therefore, if $\gcd(u,m)=1$ then $1\mid m: m=1p$ and $1\mid u: u=1q$. Hence, 
$\gcd(u,m)=1=us+mt=(1p)s+(1q)t=1(ps+qt)$ which implies that $m\mid 1$, therefore $m=\pm 1$